# How ot Automate Interaction with Dynamic Number Images in Hybrid Android App

Tags: automation, robotframework, ui-automation, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I need you help, i have requirement to automated the attached screen, is from a hybrid app run in android . the issue i am facing is that the shown number from xml layout are Images inside android.view.ViewGroup not button with value and there position on the screen changes everytime the screen is loaded means they don't have fix position.

I have tried to use [automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/) but with no success.
kindly let me know if there is a way to automate this screen and which tool you think is suitable in this case.

I am thinking about using OCR , so that it can read the number in the image and give me back the x,y coordinates of target number. what do you think ? can you suggest a suitable library for this?

Have a fabulous time wherever you are now in the plant :).

screen images: note that the position of the number changes every time the screen is load , not fixed.

---

[screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGbQ4.png)

[screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGuUF.png)

---

XML layout: [screen_layout.xml](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/hRLSKuO7#link)

i have tries to use Automate but didn't work, i expected to click of the desired number to fill the input ( 4 green dots) using automated way.

Comment: Because you need to find only numbers, it might be easier to save bitmaps of numbers and use OpenCV or similar to find their coordinates.